# Google Calendar webhook test

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am pretty much new to google integration and I am trying to integrate google calendar. I am able to get the calendar list and its events via API.

Now, I want my webhook to be called whenever there is any change in a google calendar. I want to use google push notification for that so I can create a channel and register my webhook there. Now the question is, how to test that if my webhook working properly. Because Google is not allowing to add localhost as a varified domain. I tried to use Ngrok but google is also not allowing me to register that domain.

Is there any way to test google webhook locally? If there is any other way to implement a google webhook, please share that too.

Answer (score 1):

After implementing your controller and the action inside your API, go to postman put the necessary URL and change the values of the fields below.

Get the values from the Calendar API Watch function that you should have been implemented before.

Here is a very useful [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) to help you through out the whole implementation.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To use [Push notifications in calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) you need to [register your domain](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#registering-your-domain). Also you need to use HTTPS (not HTTP) as a transport protocol.

For now there is no way I can think of to test this webhook locally without a verified domain.